# I want to solve this error AttributeError: module 'tokenization' has no attribute 'FullTokenizer'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I'm working on tensorflow2 but I'm facing error on importing tokenization like below . 
I have alredy tried pip3 install some tensorflow version 1.0~2.0 and the packages of tokenizer and tokenization but still not working . could you give me advice to solve this error ??

```
error message

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_count_tokenization.py", line 26, in <module>
    my_tokenizer = tokenization.FullTokenizer(vocab_file=vocab_path)
AttributeError: module 'tokenization' has no attribute 'FullTokenizer'
```

```
import tokenization
import codecs
import numpy as np

vocab_path = "./model_ch/vocab.txt"
max_seq_length = 128   

file0 = "./task/message.tsv"
f0 = codecs.open(file0, "r", "utf-8")
lines = f0.readlines()
f0.close()

len_file = len(lines)
count = np.zeros([len_file])
count0 = np.zeros([len_file])
my_tokenizer = tokenization.FullTokenizer(vocab_file=vocab_path)

#file1 = "./task_data_ch/%s_count.tsv" % filename
file1 = "./task/message_count.tsv"
f1 = codecs.open(file1, "w", "utf-8")
f1.write("%s\t%s\t%s\r\n" % ("label","count","count_truncated"))

for i in range(1,len_file):
  a = lines[i]
  a = a.split("\t")
  text = a[1]
  token = my_tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  print(token)
  count[i] = len(token) + 2   # for [CLS] and [SEP]
  if count[i] > max_seq_length:
    count0[i] = max_seq_length
  else:
    count0[i] = count[i]
  f1.write("%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (i-1,int(count[i]),int(count0[i])))

sum0 = int(np.sum(count0))
sum1 = int(np.sum(count))
print(sum0, sum1)
print(int(len_file-1))
f1.write("Total: %s, %s" % (sum1,sum0))
f1.close()
```

```
the result of pip3 list 

tensorboard                        2.2.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit             1.6.0.post3
tensorflow-estimator               2.2.0
tokenization                       1.0.7
tokenizer                          2.0.5
```

Comment: Hie @kento Tamura why don't you use NLTK directly instead of tokenization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below piece of code will enable TF 2.0 for you.

```
# Colab has two versions of TensorFlow installed: a 1.x version and a 2.xversion. 
# Collab currently uses TF 1.x by default
# To enable TF2 to execute the following code

%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

Then, Import the nltk with specific requirements such as stop word, tokenization, etc.

```
import nltk
nltk.download("popular")
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
```

And the below code will tokenize your sentences and if you want your sentences to be tokenized that can also be done using

> tokens = sent_tokenize("Your paragraphs or multiple sentences")

```
text = "I love NLP and I will learn NLP in 2 months"
words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
words
```

Comment: I'm so so so sorry for too late response !! I didn't realize I haven't still response . yea as you mentioned , nltk worked well ! Than you so much !!